# MacBook Pro wifi vs. iPhone wifi in same location

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, internet

I've noticed that every minute or so, the wifi on my 15" MacbookPro Retina just doesn't seem to work, yet the icon displays full bars (4/4). In the exact same location my iPhone shows 2/3 or 3/3 bars and the wifi works excellent. What is wrong with my MacBook Pro? How do I resolve this? Shouldn't the MacBook get better reception as it has a larger and more powerful antenna?

Comment: What makes you think wifi is the problem with your MB?  In other words what indication does it give you "every minute or so" that wifi is not working??

Comment: Pages will either take a long time to load or simply not load at all. Cloud apps like Google drive indicate they go offline. Wifi icon stays full bars though. My iPhone works fine while my MacBook does not at the same times

Comment: When your Wifi fails your phone falls back to cellular, so it could be losing wifi as well without you knowing...

Comment: I suspect it's not wifi, but I don't know what to suggest.  It may be your internet connection (which is one hop upstream from wifi).

Comment: @AllInOne when an iPhone goes to LTE the wifi bars go away, in my case they remain so it's still on wifi. Also tested with iPhone on airplane mode so only wifi would work anyway.